# Git (no branch) with uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I am currently on `(no branch)`  with uncommitted changes. I would like to check out a different branch and throw away all my changes.

When I do

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

I get:

```
**error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        avar/libs/video_preprocessing_controller/video_preprocessing_controller.cpp
        bbn/tracker/libs/init_and_cont_tracks/init_and_cont_tracks.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting**
```

I don't want to `commit` nor `stash` my changes. Do I not have a third option? (ignore them/throw them away)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git checkout -f [branch name]`

Alternatively, to throw away your local changes first, you can go with

```
git checkout .
git checkout [branch name]
```

Comment: Thanks! `git checkout [branch_name]` reports the error that I posted, but  `git checkout -f` seems to do the trick.